# Switch between persistent and non-persistent session based on user selection

Tags: node.js, express, session

I am trying to create a login feature for my web application using express-session as a session middleware and connect-mongo as persistent store. I was able to implement persistent session using the mongo store, before which, express-session supported in-memory session until users closed the browser.

I am providing a feature wherein, if the user, while logging in, selects a checkbox "Keep me signed in", creates a persistent session for n days, but if not, by default, the session should expire on closing the browser. I have lost the ability to clear session on browser exit now that I have implemented persistent store with connect-mongo.

How do I switch between both session approach for my feature.

1. Is it possible to clear session on browser exit in connect-mongo? If so how to I handle the browser event.
2. Is it practical to implement session based on user selection, and implement persistent store only if user chooses to keep him signed in?

Please suggest better option or one that I don't see yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you confuse 2 different things.

`express-session` uses different stores to retain sessions on server side. It can be in-memory storage which is cleared out once the node process exits (not when a browser is closed) or it can be persistent storage on disk/in a database.

If you read `connect-mongo` README carefully you'll notice that it clears sessions from DB based on cookie's expiration date or if not set it will use `ttl` option you can provide (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo#session-expiration)).

But this is on the server side and it doesn't affect the expiration date of the cookie which browsers respect.

A session cookie is a cookie that has no expiration date set, i.e. such cookie will be deleted by a browser when it's closed. Initially, you can set `maxAge` of a cookie using [`cookie.maxAge`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookiemaxage) option that you pass to `session` method of `express-session`. You can use this value as a session expiration date for a user which selects "Keep me signed in" checkbox.

For users who don't select "Keep me signed in" you can adjust the cookie expiration dynamically by accessing it via `req.session.cookie` inside your endpoint where you have your user's sign-in logic:

```js
req.session.cookie.expires = false
```

This info is also in `express-session` docs [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsessioncookie).

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this out and get back.

Comment: Hello @GProst, this worked out for me perfectly. Although, I implemented this for Passport local login strategy, at some point, would like to apply for passport Facebook strategy as well. Thanks. Marking as correct answer.